# Nodejs WebSocket response is encrypted or not readable (connecting to a exchange socket)

Tags: node.js, encryption, websocket, socket.io, decode

I am trying to make a request to a WebSocket of a crypto-exchange to get live market data for analysis.
In the Browser the data is shown in readable Text as it is used to populate the orderbook.
When trying to connect to it via nodejs I am getting a hex code that when converted still doesn't make sense.

```
 const WebSocket = require('ws');

    const sendData = '{"method":"deals.subscribe","params":["ETHBTC"],"id":18}'
    
    // Establish a WebSocket connection to the echo server
    const ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.exchnageAddres.com');
   
    ws.addEventListener('open', () => {

      console.log('Sending:', sendData);
      // Send message to the WebSocket server
      ws.send(sendData);

    });
    
    ws.addEventListener('message', event => {
      
      console.log('Received:', event.data);
    });
```

Response:

```
Received: <Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 ab 56 4a 2d 2a ca 2f 52 b2 52 c8 2b cd c9 d1 51 50 2a 4a 2d 2e cd 29 01 f2 ab 95 8a 4b 12 4b 4a 8b 81 4c a5 e2 d2 e4 e4 ... 23 more bytes>
Received: <Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 9d 9a df 8a 5c 47 0e c6 5f 25 cc 75 28 24 95 a4 52 ed 65 96 85 7d 80 dc 85 5c 78 d7 86 35 d8 89 89 ed 8b 10 f2 ee fb 95 ... 2012 more bytes>
Received: <Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 55 8c b1 0a 83 30 14 45 7f 45 de 5c 42 e2 6b 92 da d1 52 e8 07 b8 89 43 da 04 2a 18 0d 26 19 44 fc f7 e6 15 3a 74 3d f7 ... 106 more bytes>
```

How can I connect to the ws in node?
Do I have to use a certificate or anything? Would be awesome if someone could help me out here.

Testing the connection on a chrome extension is giving me a Blob object but I can't really convert that to an array.

Using Burp Decoder works but only there.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: `1f 8b` is gzip compression

Comment: How can I unpack that? I tried zlib. maybe you have an idea?

Comment: The `ws` client would normally do it for you. Check the request/response for a `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header with `permessage-deflate`. otherwise they are doing compression above the protocol. [ws decompress](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/237960e915b3f41b8c7aabfa5c938171976f2978/lib/permessage-deflate.js#L338)